# Cutom tableview header not correct width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `XIB` that I'm using for my `tableView` header.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      let view =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomHeader", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomHeader
      //  view.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width doesn't work
      return view
}
```

I have the width of the `XIB` set in `storyboard`, but I need the width to be dynamically equal to the width of my `viewController`.

The subclass of my `XIB` is a `UIView`. The width was correct when I subclassed as a `UITableViewCell`, but I was getting some undesired side effects with that I read is fixed by just subclassing as `UIView` instead.

Where can I set the width of the `XIB` to be equal to the `tableView`?

Comment: The width of your header should match the width of your tableview, maybe it's the width of your tableview you need to tweak?

Comment: I just have the tableview pinned w/ autolayout to be the same size as my ViewController. Even with the code I commented out the size of the nib doesn't change, even if I hardcode it.

Comment: Do you have any code in `layoutSubview` method in `CustomHeader` class?

Comment: @KarthickSelvaraj I didn't. I tried setting the width in there and there's still no change visable to the width on launch. It's still pulling the width from what I set it in the .xib